# Why do invres and invresz give me identical results, but freqs and freqz give completely different results?

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I'm using *scipy.signal.invresz*() to generate a digital filter from a pole/residue specification. I notice that using the *invres*() function gives me the same result. However, using *freqz* vs. *freqs* to generate the plotting data give me drastically different plots; why?

```
%matplotlib inline

import random
import numpy        as np
import scipy.signal as sig

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Simulation configuration
n_bits        = 128
samps_per_bit = 32
symbols       = [1, -1]
peaking_mag   = 12         # (dB)

# Generate the oversampled random symbol stream.
u = np.array([random.choice(symbols) for i in xrange(n_bits)]).repeat(samps_per_bit)

# Generate the peaking filter (i.e. - CTLE).
p1 = -1. / samps_per_bit
p2 = -2. / samps_per_bit
z  = p1 / pow(10., peaking_mag / 20.)
r1 = (z - p1) / (p2 - p1)
r2 = 1. - r1

# I get the same values for 'b' and 'a', whether I use invres, or invresz.
b, a = sig.invresz([r1, r2], [p1, p2], [])
print b, a
b, a = sig.invres([r1, r2], [p1, p2], [])
print b, a

# But, I get drastically different plots, depending upon my use of freqz vs. freqs.
# I was expecting to get similar plots, as long as I was consistent in my choice of S vs. Z domain.
# That is: use invresz/freqz, or invres/freqs.
w, h = sig.freqz(b, a)
plt.plot(w, abs(h))
plt.figure()
w, h = sig.freqs(b, a)
plt.plot(w, abs(h))
```

[ 1.          0.00784965] [ 1.          0.09375     0.00195312]
[ 1.          0.00784965] [ 1.          0.09375     0.00195312]

Out[16]:
[image: Showing plot difference, freqz vs. frees.]

Comment: the code,  data  to reproduce the problem is expected

Comment: Code, and output, added, as requested by @f5r5e5d.

Comment: The second plot above, which uses freqs(), is correct.